Issues Upgrading from Catel 5.12 to 6.0.3
[Issue #1]
I am trying to upgrade to the latest Catel 6.0.3 Core from 5.12.  Getting compile error on AutoRegisterTypesViaAttributes not existing.  The Catel documentation still shows this property.
[Issue #2]
Getting a compile error indicating that ServiceLocatorRegistraion is not an attribute class.
[Issue #3]
ViewModelBase seems to no longer have a RaisePropertyChanged method that takes the old and new value.  The Catel documentation still shows this method.
I can't find any documentation on these changes.

[1] This feature has been removed from Catel 6.x. Auto registration via attributes has been removed since it's a low / never used feature.
If you feel you need this part in your solution, you can copy the code from the (MIT licensed) 5.x branches.
[2] The Old and New value have been removed for performance / allocation reasons as well. Also, it's not the best way to deal with data changes (except for UI updates). It's better to have your business logic handle actual data changes and raise the corresponding events.
